# Полностью перезаписать один файл xlsx в другой файл через openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

[image: Суть моего задания]

Сначала я хочу полностью перезаписать файл, т.е. скопировать эту таблицу в другую и через формулы сделать сортировку и добавить среднюю успеваемость. Помогите, пожалуйста, скопировать данные в другую таблицу.